# PyQT4 form submission response

Tags: python, forms, submit, pyqt4, response

I'm trying to make a web **scraper** using PyQT4. I'm trying to scrape a public phonebook (yellowpages). I already have some experience using "requests" library, but in this case, I can't use it because the page that I need to send request to has a random string generated at the end. Also I should mention that it is not a classic form, actually the javaScript function on the website takes whatever the user inputs in the form fields and add it all together in a form of a link. At the end it adds random generated string and it redirects you to that page. Thats why I resorted to using PyQT4. My idea is to use PyQT4 to manipulate the DOM elements. I'm completely new to PyQT4, but I managed to do the first part. I successfully fill the input fields and press the button, but I don't know how to get the stuff from the response page. My idea was to somehow obtain the current URL of the response page and then find in it what I need while the page is still loaded, because once it reloads the link becomes dead (because of the random generated string). I'm sorry for writing this much, but I tried to be specific about the problem. Also I'm sorry for my english, it is not my native language. I'm using Python 3.4 if thats relevant somehow. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit
import sys
import os

x = 0

def executeJs():
    global web
    web.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('Mesto').value='Ruma';")
    web.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('Ulica').value='marka pericina kamenjara';")
    web.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('Broj').value='8';")
    web.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('btn_trazi').click()")

    print ("js executed\n")

def onDone():
    global x
if x == 0:
    x = 1
    executeJs()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.11811.rs/BeleStrane/Index"))
web.loadFinished.connect(onDone)


web.show()
app.exec_()
```